# highCharts overlay dataLabels

Tags: highcharts, overlap

have a problem with overlay dataLabels on columns and lines:
[image]

[image]

have plugin standart functions to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this solution is not supported, but you can adapt this `solution`: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/.